# No CMAKE_C_COMPILER found while trying to build Clang

Tags: software-installation, cmake

I'm trying to build Clang using the steps shown here: https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html.

However, I'm receiving the No CMAKE_C_COMPILER found error.

These were my steps:

1. First, I opened Terminal.
2. Then I used the command git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git.
3. cd llvm-project
4. mkdir build
5. cd build
6. cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm

I then receive the following error (screenshot below):
[image]
[image]

Could someone please advise what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are wasting your time at first. The Clang is already [packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=clang) for all Ubuntu versions.

To install it open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clang llvm
```